# Multiselect Controls available for Excel addin

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Actually am new to creating excel add-in using VSTO.

My requirement is when user select a cell, it should change to Multi select control , and he will select few items in that.

when the selection goes to another cell, newly selected cell should become Multiselect control and old cell should retain the values alone, control needs to be removed.

**I tried  below**

I attached selection change event for a cell, and in that event am creating the combo box and populating values.

And when selection changes to new cell, how to remove that control from the old cell ??

and also there is no Mutiselect property for combo box. Is there any appropriate control for this feature ?

Is there any active X controls ?

Any samples for this kind of requirement would be great help.

Please guide.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Contextures has some great info on this  kind of thing. Start here: http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2009/09/18/select-multiple-items-from-excel-data-validation-list/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox` as a multiselected combobox. I think it is better to set `CheckOnClick=true`

It is a right way to listen the selection change event. But this event will not tell you the infomation about where your selection leave from.

You can either save the cell location by yourself in context or save the cell location in the ComboBox and always try to hidden the ComboBoxes that not match the `currentSelection` cell.